# PowerShell comparing directory and copy to another directory

Tags: powershell, powershell-ise

I have the following structure:

```
C:\one\web.config
C:\two\web_rollback.config
C:\three\    ( this is empty , it is where I want to copy to
```

In my Powershell  file.ps1 I have the following code:

```
$Folder1 = Get-childitem  "C:\one\"
$Folder2 = Get-childitem  "C:\two\"
$Folder3 = Get-childItem  "C:\three\"

Compare-Object $Folder1 $Folder2 -Property Name, Length | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"} | ForEach-Object {
    Copy-Item "$Folder1\$($_.name)" -Destination $Folder3 -Force}
```

HOWEVER,  I get this error below  WHY?

```
PS C:\windows\system32> C:\pscripts\compareobject.ps1
Copy-Item : Cannot find path 'C:\windows\system32\Web.config\Web_Rollback.config' because it does not exist.
```

Comment: Your code isn't as self-documenting as you had probably hoped.  Could you edit your question to include what you expected to happen (what you wanted the code to do, and what you thought the resulting directory should be)? "It dun broke" isn't a very good place to begin troubleshooting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You chose misleading variable names and fell into the hole you dug yourself.

```
$Folder1 = Get-childitem  "C:\one\"
$Folder2 = Get-childitem  "C:\two\"
$Folder3 = Get-childItem  "C:\three\"
```

These instructions will fill the variables with the *child items* of the given folders.

```
Copy-Item "$Folder1\$($_.name)" -Destination $Folder3 -Force
```

This instruction, however, uses `$Folder1` and `$Folder3` as if they contained the *folder path* (which they don't).

On top of that, your code will fail, because `Compare-Object -Property Name, Length` will always produce `web_rollback.config` as the result for the side indicator `=>` (since the names of the items in `C:\one` and `C:\two` are different even if the file sizes aren't), and no file with that name is present in `C:\one`.

Another flaw with your approach is that you're relying on a difference in size for detecting a change between the two files. This check will fail if for instance a value was changed from `0` to `1`.

Change your code to something like this:

```
$config   = "C:\one\web.config"
$rollback = "C:\two\web_rollback.config"
$target   = Join-Path "C:\three" (Get-Item $config).Name

if ([IO.File]::ReadAllText($config) -ne [IO.File]::ReadAllText($rollback)) {
  Copy-Item $rollback -Destination $target -Force
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What happens if you remove the trailing slash in the folder path?

```
$Folder1 = Get-childitem  "C:\one"
$Folder2 = Get-childitem  "C:\two"
$Folder3 = Get-childItem  "C:\three"
```

Because if you expanded the variable $Folder1 you would get

```
Copy-Item "$Folder1\$($_.name)"

Copy-Item "C:\One\\$($_.name)"
```

?????

Comment: Same result.  It must be smart enough life in .net with working with directory and files and doing a "combine"